# What is the difference between isAuthorized() and using the Acl component in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, authorization, cakephp-2.1

I'm still a newbie in cake. 
Suppose you have a table users that has a group_id and a table called groups
Groups:

- id   role
- 1    Admin
- 2    Teacher
- 3    Student

I'm wondering, what is the difference between for example, using the isAuthorized function to authorize the user to access a certain action and between using the Acl to restrict his access? Is one method more secure than the other?

Also, I was wondering if there is any 'Cakish' way to for example:
- Allow admin to access the edit action
- Allow a student to access the edit action, but restrict him from changing a certain field.

For example, suppose a student is editing the table Users which has the following fields: username, password, group_id . He can edit the password but not the group_id and the username. While the admin can edit both. The way I am implementing this is checking inside the controller, after the user has posted, his group_id , and unsetting the field username and group_id according to his privileges. Is that a proper way of implementing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACL (or Access Control List) is a method of separating the logic of who has access to what from your code. With isAuthorized() you have to manually add code for each possible type of access. Also, ACLs allow (recursive) grouping and matrix-like access (like "allow access to all warriors but not those of race Gremlin"); the documentation of CakePHP is quite extensive.

However, what I personally find lacking in Cake's ACLs is restricting access to *specific* items. For example, a student may view his results but not from other students; i.e. he may call /results/view/10, /results/view/49 and /results/view/87 but no others. I have not been able to do this with ACLs.

As to editing: it's generally a bad idea to show/post all data, then remove what you deem unnecessary. You're bound to forget a field one day and then you have a bug or vulnerability. I recommend using the Security component to prevent form tampering, then only add those fields to the form that a user may edit, depending on access level.

The CakePHP documentation tells you to manually add the fields you want to save in the POST action of your controller, but that means you have to maintain the list of fields at 2 places: in your view with the form and in the controller. Add code to include/exclude fields based on access level and you have a maintanance headache. With Security anti-tampering users can't add fields manually to manipulate the POST data.